# If $G$ has order $325$, then $G$ is abelian. If in addition $G$ has exactly $4$ elements of order $5$, then determine its isomorphism class.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

We have that, $|G| = 325 = 5^2 * 13$. From the Sylow theorems we can obtain that, $n_{13} = 1$ and $n_{5} = 1$, the Sylow groups of order $13$ and $5^2$ respectively. We let $H$ be the Sylow subgroup of order $13$ and we let $K$ be the Sylow subgroup of order $5^2$. Since $n_{5} = 1$ and $n_{13} = 1$, from Sylow theorems we can conclude that both $H$ and $K$ are normal, we have that $H$ and $K$ are both cyclic ( because $|K|$ = 5^2 where $5$ is a prime); hence, abelian. In fact, $H \simeq\mathbb{Z}_{13}$. We have that,
$$H \times K \simeq G,$$
since $|HK| = 5^2*13 = 325$ because $H \cap K = \{e\}$, which means $G$ is abelian since it is a direct sum of two abelian groups. If in addition $G$ has exactly $4$ elements of order $5$, then $K = \mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5}$; hence, the isomorphism class has been determine for $G$.

Does my proof look good? Any issues? Thanks.

Comment: Justify why having exactly four elements of order five forces that specific $K$, even if it was by brute force.

Comment: How many elements of $\Bbb Z_5 \times \Bbb Z_5$ have order $5$?

Comment: @TravisWillse, ok I messed that one up, it should have been $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$. Thanks!

Comment: For the first question, you should not assume that $K$ is cyclic!